# Problem connection with ppp

Tags: pi-3, ppp

i use wvdial for configurate ppp connection via PCIe (LE910C1-EU).
This is my configuration:

```
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=5,"IP","wireless.twilio.com"
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Phone = *99#
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2
Username = " "
Password = " "
Baud = 9600
```

when i launch command

```
sudo wvdial
```

the channel ppp0 created.
I digit

```
ifconfig ppp0
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,,NOARP,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
      inet 26.67.58.219 netmask 255.255.255.255 destination 10.64.64.64
      ppp txqueuelen 3 (Point-to-Point Protocol)
      RX packets 5 bytes 62 (62.0 B)
      RX error 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
      TX packets 7 bytes 129 (129.0 B)
      TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

but if i want ping 8.8.8.8 it doesn't answer...
I can't surf on chromium.

What can it miss in the configuration?

Comment: Do you use **Raspbian**? Can you ping `10.64.64.64`? Please edit your question and add the output of this command: `ip route`.

Comment: Yes. Now it running.

Answer (score 1):

Now it run.
I must change a configuration in file wvdial.config because i use contest 5

```
Phone = *99***5#
```

and i write

```
sudo route add default dev ppp0
```